# Jetpack's Camerax - is there functionality for taking burst of images, or saving DNG file?

Tags: android, android-camerax

I have read tutorial for camerax(https://developer.android.com/training/camerax), and also some documentation(https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture). But I didn't found part responsible for taking burst of images, nor saving to DNG file(RAW format). I have encounter similar, but not answered questions in issues on github (https://github.com/android/camera/issues). So I am reposting here the questions.

Comment: https://github.com/android/camera-samples/issues/27
As per this closed issue, DNG isn't officially supported.

"In theory it may work but it's untested and you are treading the waters of device-dependent implementations -- since not all devices support RAW format. The focus of CameraX so far has been on JPEG because all devices must support it to pass CTS."

Answer (score 0):

After long time, I see that capturing RAW images by the phone is so niche problem, that it's better to have own dedicated software. It's pretty easy to implement it with Camera2 API.